# Finding the count of common values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A 1 | B 1 | A 2 |
| B 1 | C 2 | B 1 |
| C 1 |  | D 1 |
| D1 |  |  |

I want to find the common values in between to columns. And return the count of common values between all the columns. That is intersection of 1st column and 2nd column. Intersection of all the columns

Using python

Comment: does set(data[“A”]).intersection(set(data[“B”]) solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` intersections with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

common = reduce(lambda a, b: a&b,
                [set(df[c].dropna()) for c in df])
# {'B 1'}

len(common)
# 1
```

To limit to a particular list of columns:

```
list_of_cols = ['A', 'B']

common = reduce(lambda a, b: a&b,
                [set(df[c].dropna()) for c in list_of_cols])

print(len(common))
```